# Core Data table getting wiped out when implementing background fetch for app icon badge in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios7

I am trying to implement a background fetch in my AppDelegate.m to get the app icon badge to reflect an updated record count by pulling the latest record count from a web service via RestKit (not shown here).  When I simulate a BackGroundFetch in Xcode everything works fine.  When the background fetch runs on my iPhone 5S, my entire table "TicketList" gets wiped out with no data.  Here is the code.  Has anyone experienced anything similar and can anyone offer some advice as to what i am doing wrong?  I've taken out the ReskKit lookup to simplify the code and debug to see if it would have any affect. I've looked at other postings and haven't been able to find an answer as to why this is happening.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Added this code for the app icon badge functionality
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

*/
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    intAvailCount = 0;
    [self setUpCoreDataStack];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"TicketList" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    self.ticketListData = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    if ([ticketListData count] != 0){
        //Perform loop through TicketList SQLite DB and count using intAvailCount
        TicketList *info = [ticketListData objectAtIndex:0];

        for (info in ticketListData) {
            //Check to see if tickets in table have been added to do
            intAvailCount++;
        }
        //End Loop
    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = intAvailCount;
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

-(void)setUpCoreDataStack
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSBundle allBundles]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    NSURL *url = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TicketList.sqlite"];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionComplete,
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES};

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];
    if (!store)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store. Error %@",error);

        NSError *deleteError = nil;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&deleteError])
        {
            error = nil;
            store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];
        }

        if (!store)
        {
            // Also inform the user...
            NSLog(@"Failed to create persistent store. Error %@. Delete error %@",error,deleteError);
            abort();
        }
    }
    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
}
```

Comment: Try to use – countForFetchRequest:error: to get the count of ticket list objects instead of counting them using for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, it still wouldn't solve my problem of my table getting wiped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I moved the call to setUpCoreDataStack to the 1st method in my example (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) which gets called on app startup and my problem was solved. Not exactly sure why this was happening in the 1st place but, i think it had something to do with my setUpCoreDataStack being called every time the perform background fetch method got triggered.